# Crystal Reports V11 Showing different boolean values per machine

Tags: crystal-reports, visual-foxpro, crystal-reports-xi

I'm getting a weird issue with Crystal - I have a basic report that displays records dependant on a boolean value ('open') being true.  However, on some PCs it works fine, on others it just shows displays a blank report.

Having done a bit of checking into this, viewing the SQL query seems to indicate that there's an issue with how Crystal is interpreting the boolean value on different machines.

If we select 'Show SQL query' on each of the machines, the ones that don't work show the boolean section as:

```
`support`.`open`=1
```

The ones that work show:

```
 `support`.`open`=.T.
```

...which seems more realistic due to the datasource being a VFP table via an ODBC driver.

I can't quite figure this one out - I suppose it's possible it's something to do with the ODBC driver.  Does anybody have any clues as to why this might be happening?

Thanks

Comment: Obvious question, are they all the same OS, version of odbc driver, crystal. Service packs as well?

Comment: The one I'm comparing against is the same OS, same version of the driver, seems to be a slightly later version of the Crystal viewer .dll.

Answer (score 0):

The boolean should be directly interpreted through the ODBC...  I would change the query to just have

Where 'support.open'

If logical, it will only be .T. / .F.   or  true / false   or 1 / 0... Let the ODBC handler handle it for you.

--- Edit via comment.

I wasn't referring to Crystal's report formula, but the query...  But if thats the issue in Crystal, I would change the query that is RETRIEVING the data to be...

IIF( support.open, "YES", "NO " ) as ItemIsOpen

VFP OleDB / ODBC should recognize the IIF() and return the column to a string of "YES" or "NO " respectively... Then use the "ItemIsOpen" column in your report instead of the "support.open" column.

Comment: Thanks, but the query I'm showing is the Crystal interpretation of the SQL - as far as actually setting values, if I check in the Crystal formula editor it does show it as "{support.open} and..."

Comment: The query itself is actually fully in Crystal, there's nothing I can edit other than Crystals report formula, which is essentially what's seemingly causing the problem.

Going from your idea though, I did try turning the boolean value to a string in a formula variable and then using that to define which records to show / hide, which has done the trick.  Still seems odd that one instance of Crystal would decide boolean values are 0 / 1 and other instances of Crystal would define them as .t. / .f. though...